# Dispatch generated model from mogenerator in several subdirectories

Tags: objective-c, shell, core-data, mogenerator

I use `mogenerator` to generate my entities from my `Core Data` data model.

But I have a lot of generated files and I would like dispatch them in several subdirectories like:

```
Human
  |
   ----> User
  |
   ----> Products
  |
   ----> ...

Entities
  |
   ----> User
  |
   ----> Products
  |
   ----> ...
```

For now, I have only Human and Entities subdirectories to dispatch `_Model` and `Model` files.

I could create directories and drag and drop each file in the linked subdirectories each time I generate my model with `mogenerator` but I'm looking for a smarter solution to automate this process.

I don't know if `mogenerator` can manage this or if I need to use a script file for this.

Any suggestions ?

**Update**: The main difficulty is I have to "link" models to subdirectories. For example:

`ProductA` class and `ProductB` class should be put in the same directory: `Product`

**Update 2**:

For example, I have some models to generate:

User
Recipient
AProduct (abstract base class for product)
ProductA (child class of AProduct)
ProductB (child class of AProduct)

And I would like dispatch these classes in sub directories:

```
Human
  |
   ----> User
           |
            ----> User.h
           |
            ----> User.m
  |
   ----> Products
           |
            ----> AProduct.h
           |
            ----> AProduct.m
           |
            ----> ProductA.h
           |
            ----> ProductA.m
           |
            ----> ProductB.h
           |
            ----> ProductB.m

Entities
  |
   ----> User
           |
            ----> _User.h
           |
            ----> _User.m
  |
   ----> Products
           |
            ----> _AProduct.h
           |
            ----> _AProduct.m
           |
            ----> _ProductA.h
           |
            ----> _ProductA.m
           |
            ----> _ProductB.h
           |
            ----> _ProductB.m
```

Comment: If you can provide the several sample of file names to us, it will be easy for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was enough clear. I just add an example in my OP. Please have a look.

Comment: better now, but still have question. can you explain, if the name of `AProduct.h` and `_AProduct.h`, which product folder need be assigned?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand what you're asking to me.